# Kafka kstream comparing two values from two different topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Im currently trying to send two different formats of the same event on two different topics. Lets say format A to topic A and format B to topic B.

And Format B is only sent approx 15% of the times since it's not supported for older stuff. And if B is sent there will be an A equivalent of each event.

What i want to do is listen to them at the same time and if B exists i need to discard A.

What i've tried so far is to listen on both (im using kstreams),
and doing stream - stream join

```
streamA.leftJoin(streamB, (A_VALUE, B_VALUE) -> {
                    if (B_VALUE != null && A_VALUE != null) {
                        return B_VALUE
                    } else if (A_VALUE != null && B_VALUE == null) {
                        return A_VALUE
                    }
                    return null;
                },
                JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(5)).grace(Duration.ofMinutes(15)),
                Joined.with(
                        Serdes.String(),
                        Serdes.String(),
                        Serdes.String()
                ))
```

And running tests on a load between 50-200 events/s i've seen results as such: 
number B_VALUEs sent is always correct,
but number A_VALUE is larger than expected.

I think that sometimes it's sending both A and B.

I've tried using guava cache as a "hashmap with TTL", Storing all the B Events and then comparing that way. Here i find that the total amount is always correct but there is less B events then expected meaning that sometimes it does not find a match.

If there is a better way of doing it without using databases then im open for it!

note: unique events correlated always have the same key e.g. <432, A_VALUE> , <432, B_VALUE>.

Comment: I would recommend to use a custom `transform()` and maybe punctuations. You merge both streams and feed them into the `Transformer` that has one or two attached state stores: you can either put the record into the store to buffer it, or do a lookup the a corresponding event with different format exists. At some point you would not wait any longer for the other record but forward whatever is in the store (punctuation could be helpful for this)

Comment: Thanks Matthias! 
I found an example on confluents github. Is it something similar you were thinking of ?
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/4.0.0-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/EventDeduplicationLambdaIntegrationTest.java

Comment: Yes, that should be a good starting point.

Comment: I've implemented based on the code from the example.

The issue with this implementation is:
The first event will always be sent and every duplicate will be removed.

What i want to solve is:
if an event comes in different ordering, i want to guarantee to send 1 event and only the correct one. E.g.

Ordering:
A
B
Returns B. 

B
A
Returns B. 

A
<nothing>
Return A. 

B
<nothing>
return nothing

Comment: In the DeduplicationTransformer class this would be done in the transform method. But I'm not sure how to obtain this behaviour. And i have no power of how events are sent to me so i cannot change from the source.

Comment: Well, given an event you need to be able to decide if it's your A or B event. Because different event come from different topics, you should be able to use `context.topic()` for that.

Comment: I already have a way to distinguish what message it is what i'm not able to achive is the ordering i want. Meaning no matter if A or B comes first i need to send B. Since that deduplicater sends the first message and removes all duplicates that coms after the first, it does not really care which message is sent.

Comment: Well. You need to change the code accordingly. When you receive A, and nothing is in the store, you put it into the store and don't send anything. If you receive A, and B is already in the store, you delete B from the store, and don't send anything (effectively dropping A). When you receive B, and nothing is in the store you add it to the store and send it downstream. If you receive B, and A is in the store, you delete A from the store and send B downstream. If A is in the store but you never receive a B, we eventually take A from the store, delete it and send it downstream.

Comment: Sounds good thank you so much. How do you do the last part: sending ”eventually take A from the store”

Comment: Either you do this as a "side task" during regular processing, of you may schedule a punctuation: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#defining-a-stream-processor

Comment: In lack of time i decided to do it another way, switched out the Kstreams for consumer and producer and batchprocess it and it's working fine for now but im going to try to tackle this problem when i'll have some more time :) Thanks Mathias!